# Table shows well on editing window but turns into text when posted

Tags: bug, markdown, markdown-rendering, tables

I just wrote a post over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72328258/using-result-of-select-to-assign-multiple-where-conditions) about SQL (yes, it is a basic question - I know very little about SQL). And while the preview/editing screen correctly shows the table, it disappears when actually posting. (I fixed it in the post to not hamper the quality of that post so the mangled output is not visible there anymore.)

The code:

```
But this of course will also return marie, who lives in London, not in Dublin.
|name|city|street|
|-----|------|---------------|
|marie|london|butchers_street|
|john |dublin|butchers_street|
|beth |dublin|butchers_street|
|anna |dublin|butchers_street|
```

While editing it is correct:

[image: preview window]

But after posting:

[image: after posted]

The issue is that for some reason in the preview/editing window there does not need to be a newline between the table and preceding text - it just works as is. But to get it to work on the posted version, the table has to be separate from the preceding paragraph by a newline.

I'd say this is a bug or at least an inconsistency that can be improved by making sure that the preview behaves the same as the actually posted version.